# Hola, ¿como puedo pasar este código de Jquery a Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estimados necesito de su ayuda, ¿cómo puedo pasar este código a formato javascript? es un jquery que lee archivos de la carpeta donde está alojada la pagina y las incluye en un input select html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function ()

        {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '.',
                    success: function (data) {
                       //console.log(data);
                        $(data).find("a:contains(.geojson)").each(function () {
                            $("#valores").append('<option value="'+ $(this).text() +'">'+ $(this).text() +'</option>');
                        });                 
                        
                    }
                });
        })
    </script>
<body>
<div id="fileNames"></div>
<select name="valores" id="valores">
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

agradecidos de su ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: Yo creo que es mucho menos codigo asi tal cual estas, porque si quieres hacer lo mismo con javascript puro sin usar librerias ni apis, el codigo se extendera posiblemente el doble o incluso el triple.

Comment: @Riven lo que pasa es que donde lo necesito tengo algunos problemas con la libreria de jquery y deseaba tener este fragmento de codigo como javascript, no importa si el código se extendiera

Comment: En esta página hay una guía: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tu preguntas le faltan detalles y se encuentra un poco desorganizada... tuve que acomodar un poco a fin de poder visualizarlo bien, ahora bien, para tu proposito he realizado el siguiente codigo:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

  function $ajax(body){
    return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
      const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      const data = new FormData();

      for(let prop in body){
        if(prop.toLowerCase() != 'url') data.append(prop, body[prop]);
      }

      xhttp.onload = ()=> res(xhttp.responseText);
      xhttp.onerror = e => rej(e.message);
      xhttp.open('POST', body.url, true);
      xhttp.send(data);
    });
  }
  
  $ajax({
    url: 'tu url aqui'      //debajo ira el cuerpo que deseas enviar al backend
  }).then(data =>{
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(data)).forEach(el =>{
      if(el.classList.contains("geojson")){
        let text = el.textContent;
        document.getElementById("valores").innerHTML += `<option value="${text}">${text}</option>`
      }
    });
  }).catch(e => console.error(e))

}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="fileNames"></div>

    <select name="valores" id="valores">
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

La verdad es mucho por explicar, asi que lo explicare de manera rapida, primero tenemos el objeto `Promise`, que nos permite manejar codigo asincrono para obtener ya sea una respuesta o un error atravez de sus metodos `then` o `catch`.

El objeto `XMLHttpRequest` es principalmente nuestra peticion `ajax`, sin este objeto `ajax` no existiria.

A `XMLHttpRequest` se le pueden añadir cabeceras o incluso eventos, concretamente los mas importantes son el evento `load`, y el evento `error`, el evento `load` no necesariamente dicta que todo haya ido bien, simplemente que la peticion cargo, para comprobar que efectivamente la peticion se ha realizado de manera correcta tenemos a las propiedades `readyState` y status de `XMLHttpRequest`.

Para el caso del evento `error`, es buena idea tenerlo por si ocurre algun error rechazar la promesa con el mensaje de error.

Tenemos el objeto `FormData` que permite crear un objeto por pares de valores, una `key` y un `value`, algo parecido a un `Object` en javascript.

```
for(let prop in body){
   if(prop.toLowerCase() != 'url') data.append(prop, body[prop]);
}
```

Simplemente estamos recorriendo el objeto que se requiere como parametros y le estamos asignando tanto la clave como el valor a nuestro `FormData` por cada llave o valor que le hayamos pasado a `body`.

Tenemos tambien al metodo open, que sirve para indicarle a `ajax` qué metodo vamos a usar, hacia donde vamos hacer la peticion y si deseamos que la peticion sea sincrona o asincrona.

por ultimo:

```
xhttp.send(data);
```

Que envia los datos del `FormData` que teniamos.

```
$ajax({
    url: 'tu url aqui'      //debajo ira el cuerpo que deseas enviar al backend
  }).then(data =>{
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(data)).forEach(el =>{
      if(el.classList.contains("geojson")){
        let text = el.textContent;
        document.getElementById("valores").innerHTML += `<option value="${text}">${text}</option>`
      }
    });
  }).catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Acerca de esa parte de ahi, simplemente invocamos a nuestro `$ajax`, pasandole como parametro la `url`, hay que tener en cuenta que como no estamos usando `jQuery`, pasarle cabeceras o hacer otro tipo de cosas simplemente no funcionara como lo esperas, a menos que implementes las cabeceras en tu `$ajax`.

```
Array.from
```

Lo usamos porque `document.querySelectorAll` devuelve un **HTMLCollection** y **NO** un `Array`, por lo tanto debemos transformar ese `HTMLCollection` en un `Array` usando `Array.from`, para poder que podamos usar `forEach`.

```
if(el.classList.contains("geojson")){
```

Miramos si el actual objeto recorrido contiene la clase `geojson`, en cuyo caso:

```
let text = el.textContent;
document.getElementById("valores").innerHTML += `<option value="${text}">${text}</option>`
```

Obtenemos el `texto` dentro del elemento actual recorrido y lo almacenamos en `text`, luego obtenemos al elemento con **id** `valores` y le añadimos al final un `<option>` con ciertos valores dinamicos.

**NOTA:** esto de aqui:

```
`<option value="${text}">${text}</option>`
```

**NO** es propio de `jQuery` se llaman `template strings` y permiten renderizar javascript dentro de `${}`.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta. lo empecé a probar y me daba el error 405 (Method not Allowed) (por el metodo POST), lo cambié a GET y ahí me envió de vuelta un codigo html en el 'document' con los archivos listados, pero me dió error en lo siguiente:

DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document'

en esta línea:

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(data)).forEach(el =>{

¿es porque el document es una pagina html?. es el único error que esta entregando.

Comment: No deberias devolver `HTML` desde el servidor, es de las peores cosas que puedes hacer, siempre lo ideal es devolver desde el servidor un json con los datos, y desde el frontend (javascript) encargarte de crear elementos y rellenarlos con los datos traidos por el backend. ese error se debe a que `document.querySelectorAll` necesita ya sea un tagname (`video`), un id (`#midiv`) o una clase (`.mielemento`), como no se realmente que elemento ni con que clases o id te esta llegando deberas acomodar tu backend para que los datos que lleguen funcionen con `querySelectorAll` desde javascript.